# Passing string variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm dynamically creating a button. I can pass a variable with a numerical value (1) but I can't pass a string variable.  Why?

```
function test(test1) {
  alert(test1);
}
document.write("<input type='button' value='' id=j onclick='test(1)'/>");
```

Comment: Because you don't know how to escape `"` ==>`\"`

Comment: issue is with the string formatting. use like `onclick='test(\'1\')'`

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't know the backslash would be required.  But it didn't work using single quotes.  It does work using double quotes with the backslash.

Comment: @Don It wouldn't work with single quotes because the output will be  `onclick='test('1')'`, it **would** work if you change it to this: `"<input type='button' value='' id=j onclick=\"test('1')\" />"`

Comment: Yes, that works.  Thank you.  The answer from Yury below also works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can. You just need to add quotes.

```js
function test(test1) {
  console.log(typeof test1);
}
document.write("<input type='button' value='Click' id='j' onclick='test(\"abc\")'/>");
```